# using using mid function to grab lookup value for userform?

Tags: excel, vba

Have a dummy data userform where I want to utilize a combo box value for a lookup in other fields on the page.

So I have two option buttons in case the user doesn't know the employee ID of who they're looking up. if the user clicks `name` then the combobox fills in as `name - employee id` and vice versa.

Regardless, my lookup value will always need to be that employee id.

[image]

so I am trying to use the mid function in order to execute an instant lookup for the other text fields in the userform page.

```
Private Sub cmbEmployee_Change()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim strID
    x = cmbEmployee 'combo box in picture up above
    If optName = True Then
        strID = Mid(x, InStr(x, " - ") + 1)
    Else
        strID = Mid(x, InStr(x, " - ") - 1)
    End If
    txtName.Value = Application.VLookup(CLng(strID), _
                            Worksheets("masterws").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
    txtmgrID = Application.VLookup(CLng(strID), _
                            Worksheets("masterws").Range("A:C"), 3, False)
    txtmgrName = Application.VLookup(CLng(strID), _
                            Worksheets("masterws").Range("A:D"), 4, False)
    txtReq = Application.VLookup(CLng(strID), _
                            Worksheets("masterws").Range("A:E"), 5, False)
    txtLocation = Application.VLookup(CLng(strID), _
                            Worksheets("masterws").Range("A:F"), 6, False)
End Sub
```

any ideas why the lookups aren't populating? Is this even possible?

Comment: Get rid of that `On Error Resume Next` first.

Comment: @BigBen getting a type mismatch on the `cLng` part because its not properly extracting the `employee id`. How could I revise the mid function up top to make sure i'm only extracting the number and not anything else?

Comment: But it sounds like there won't always be an `employee id` so you can't blindly use `CLng` here, right? Also, if you use `Debug.Print Mid(x, InStr(x, " - ") + 1)`, you'll see that the result is `- 44444`, in other words, `+ 1` is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: @BigBen there will always be a employee id, but it just will either be on the left or right side based on which option button is chosen by the user.

Comment: Got it. Then the problem is the `+ 1`. Also, `strID = Mid(x, InStr(x, " - ") - 1)` won't do what you want either. You might consider using `Left` for that case.

Comment: @BigBen used the split function and now its working great. thanks for the error handling suggestion